# how to display NotifyIcon Dynamically without windows form

Tags: c#, notifyicon

i want to display NotifyIcon after elapsed time is over instead of message box

here is my code :

1.this code is in my form window :

```
string message = "The " + targetGrid.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + " batch is completed!";// dataGridrow contains "00:05:22" (time) 
notify.notifyTimer(TimeSpan.Parse(rTime), message);
```

2.this is my notifyclass and notify is object of that class

```
class NotifyClass
    {
    string msg;
    public void notifyTimer(TimeSpan rts, string message)
    {
        var aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(rts.TotalMilliseconds);
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        msg = message;
    }
    private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        System.IO.Stream str = Properties.Resources.ios_notification;
        System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(str);
        player.Play();
        MessageBox.Show(msg); **// Here i want to display notifyIcon**
        player.Stop();
    }
}
```

so whow to do that please help me..

Comment: What is this running on? iOS? Something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run an "empty" Windows Application that only has a NotifyIcon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788611/how-to-run-an-empty-windows-application-that-only-has-a-notifyicon)

Comment: this is wav file for sound to that notification

Answer (score -1):

You can find a tutorial on how to add a NotifyIcon without a form [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bc4556d5-3cb4-458b-96be-6f51c68700fd/notifyicon-with-contextmenu-and-no-form?forum=Vsexpressvcs).

All you would change to make it appear is, instead of typing `notifyIcon1.Visible = true` right at the start of the program, you put that command in an event.

You still need to `notifyIcon1.Visible = false` at the end of the execution.